# Inject external resource with Gulp

Tags: gulp

I have the css file like this:

```
.container {
  {placeholer}
}
```

And I want replace the `{placeholder}` with the css from an external url, for example, `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.6/styles/dark.min.css`.

Does anybody know a **gulp plugin** that can do this? I've just read the docs about `gulp-inject` plugin but I didn't find anything about external resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`gulp-tap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-tap).

For example

```
gulp
.src('src/**/main.css')
.pipe(tap(function(file) {

    var fileContents = file._contents.toString();

    //  replace whatever you want...
    file._contents = new Buffer(fileContents.replace(regex, replacement));
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
```

Assuming you will get somehow the contents of the external file you want ( check [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) for example to fetch the file you want ) then you can do the replacement like above.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what I need, but do you know to the way to make `replacement` have the contents from the url `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.6/styles/dark.min.css`?

Comment: Like I said, check `request`. You can make a call to the url you want, and in the body you'll have the contents of the file. Save them in some variable and then read them when you do the replacement. Or however you think best.